# replace set of integers with respective string values

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql

I have a query which return the output like -- 5,4,6

Where 1 = apple, 2 = mango, 3 = banana, 4 = plum, 5 = cherry, 6 = kiwi etc.

I would like to update my output as cherry,plum,kiwi instead of 5,4,6 
How can I achieve that in the same select statment.

I am okay to hard code the values.

Please confirm

May be I did explain clearly

Here is the sample

SELECT fruits FROM t_fruitid where id  =   7

is returning me  '5,6,4'  as a single row

Now I want to update this single row output as 'cherry,plum,kiwi'

How do I do this

Thanku

Answer (score 2):

You should either query a reference table which has the integer values and the text strings in it (the preferred option) or use a case statement to do the conversion.

The preferred option

```
SELECT {YourExistingColumns}, NewTable.DescriptionColumn
FROM YourTable
JOIN NewTable ON YourTable.SomeIdColumn = NewTable.SomeIdColumn
```

Other option.

```
SELECT {YourExistingColumns}, CASE WHEN SomeColumn = 1 THEN 'apple' WHEN SomeColumn = 2 THEN 'mango' WHEN SomeColumn = 3 then 'banana' WHEN SomeColumn = 4 THEN 'plum' WHEN SomeColumn = 5 THEN 'cherry' WHEN SomeColumn = 6 THEN 'kiwi' END
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Hi
I updated by above description, please look at the below lines 

May be I did explain clearly 

Here is the sample 

SELECT fruits FROM t_fruitid where id = 7

is returning me '5,6,4' as a single row

Now I want to update this single row output as 'cherry,plum,kiwi'

How do I do this

Comment: SELECT  REPLACE(fruits, 5, 'cherry')
AS fruits_list
FROM fruitid  WHERE ID = 2
is doing for one value but I need to for all the values in the '5,6,4'
trying for the approach to replace the ids with values in the output

Comment: I got it, I was able to achieve this using 

SELECT REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE(fruits, 1, 'apple'),  2, 'mango'), 3, 'banana'), 4, 'plum'), 5, 'cherry'), 6, 'kiwi') 

Thanku